# Why does gnome-keyring-daemon fail with "Operation not permitted" in a Dev Container?

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer, gnome-keyring-daemon

I am trying to follow the Zowe CLI [Configuring Secure Credential Store on headless Linux operating systems](https://docs.zowe.org/stable/user-guide/cli-configure-scs-on-headless-linux-os/) instructions, however when I run the following commands...

```bash
export $(dbus-launch)
gnome-keyring-daemon -r --unlock --components=secrets
```

...I get this error...

```
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon: Operation not permitted
```

I'm running in a Visual Studio Code Dev Container based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/java` image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/bitwarden/directory-connector/issues/17#issuecomment-499935581) which described the requirement to start containers with `--cap-add=IPC_LOCK` to run `gnome-keyring-daemon`, I was able to get the Zowe CLI to work by updating my [devcontainer.json file](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/) with...

```json
    "capAdd": [
        "IPC_LOCK"
    ],
```